# Activity multiprocess attribute

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-permissions

Inside the manifest file, an `Activity` may be assigned the attribute `android::multiprocess`. According to the  documentation, when set to true, this activity should run in the same process as the calling activity.
My question is: what permissions will be assigned to this activity should another app call it?